# Select from (select union all select) error

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is wrong with this query:

```
SELECT AVG(price) as AVG_price FROM 
(
 (SELECT price FROM PC, Product WHERE maker = 'A' AND Product.model = PC.model)
  UNION ALL
 (SELECT price FROM Laptop, Product WHERE maker = 'A' AND Product.model = Laptop.model)
)
```

It gives the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: "Incorrect syntax near ')'"

Comment: Remove the ( ) around each SELECT. But you still have to add JOIN conditions to get the correct answer!!!

Comment: alias the derived tables.

Comment: where should i have join conditions?

Comment: Sorry, I'm blind. Not used to old style explicit joins...

Comment: @jarlh, my brain always does a hiccup when I encounter those too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This..

```
SELECT AVG(d.price) as AVG_price FROM 
(
 SELECT price FROM PC, Product WHERE maker = 'A' AND Product.model = PC.model
  UNION ALL
 SELECT price FROM Laptop, Product WHERE maker = 'A' AND Product.model = Laptop.model
) as d
```

Comment: Your Welcome @ВадимХадкевич

Answer (score 2):

Alias the derived table and converted to SQL-92 ANSI standards.

```
SELECT AVG(price) as AVG_price FROM 
(
 SELECT price FROM PC INNER JOIN Product on Product.model = PC.model
 WHERE maker = 'A' 
  UNION ALL
 SELECT price FROM Laptop  INNER JOIN Product on Product.model = Laptop.model
 WHERE maker = 'A'
) B
```

Answer (score 2):

With modern style `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT AVG(price)
FROM 
(
 SELECT price
 FROM PC JOIN Product ON Product.model = PC.model
 WHERE maker = 'A'

 UNION ALL

 SELECT price
 FROM Laptop JOIN Product  ON Product.model = Laptop.model
 WHERE maker = 'A'
) as dt
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this syntax.

```
SELECT AVG(price) as AVG_price FROM 
(
  (SELECT price FROM PC, Product WHERE maker = 'A' AND Product.model =  PC.model)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT price FROM Laptop, Product WHERE maker = 'A' AND Product.model = Laptop.model)
) AS ALIAS_NAME
```

I have added the ALIAS_NAME at the end of the query. may this solves ur problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give the inline table an alias

```
SELECT AVG(price) as AVG_price FROM 
(
     (SELECT price FROM PC, Product WHERE maker = 'A' AND Product.model = PC.model)
      UNION ALL
     (SELECT price FROM Laptop, Product WHERE maker = 'A' AND Product.model = Laptop.model)
) tableAlias
```

should do the trick

Comment: No problem @ВадимХадкевич - looks like you got a handful of answers all the same. It's very decent of you to thank everybody individually - fair play.